# VB Payroll Calculator ( For..Next Loop help please?)

Tags: vba

I am trying to figure out why my For...Next loop will not execute properly in this program. It was supposed to allow the user to input payroll information for 4 different employees; however, it just copies the user input for the first employee 4 times in the listbox. I entered the code as I understand it from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zxkf5z4b%28v=vs.71%29.aspx so I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I've tried changing the loop counter from 0 to 1 but that did not resolve the error.

```
    Public Class Payroll

Private Sub btnExit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnExit.Click
   Me.Close()          'Exit application.
End Sub

Private Sub btnClear_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnClear.Click
txtHoursWorked.Clear()
txtHourlyPayRate.Clear()
txtStateTaxRate.Clear()     ' Clear textboxes and set focus to txtHoursWorked.
txtFedTaxRate.Clear()
txtFICA.Clear()

txtHoursWorked.Focus()
End Sub

Private Sub btnCalculate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCalculate.Click
Dim intCount As Integer = 0   ' Loop Counter.
Dim intGrossPay As Integer  ' To hold gross pay.
Dim intStateTax As Integer  ' To hold state tax withholding.
Dim intFedTax As Integer    ' To hold fed tax withholding.
Dim intFICA As Integer      ' To hold FICA withholding.
Dim intNetPay As Integer    ' To hold net pay.
Dim strPay As String        ' To hold output.

For intCount = 1 To 4 Step 1
'Calculate gross pay.
intGrossPay = txtHourlyPayRate.Text * txtHoursWorked.Text

'Calculate state income tax withholding.
intStateTax = intGrossPay * txtStateTaxRate.Text

'Calculate fed tax withholding.
intFedTax = intGrossPay * txtFedTaxRate.Text

' Calculate FICA witholding.
intFICA = intGrossPay * txtFICA.Text

'Calculate net pay.
intNetPay = intGrossPay - (intStateTax + intFedTax + intFICA)

If (intStateTax + intFedTax + intFICA) < intGrossPay Then
    ' Create a string to display.
    strPay = ("Employee number" & (intCount.ToString) & ": " & "Gross pay is " & (intGrossPay.ToString("C")) & ". " &
        "State tax withholding is " & (intStateTax.ToString("C")) & ". " & "Federal tax withholding is " & (intFedTax.ToString("C")) &
        ". " & "FICA withholdings is " & (intFICA.ToString("C")) & ". " & "Net pay is " & (intNetPay.ToString("C")) & ". ")

    ' Add string to listbox."
    lstEmployeePay.Items.Add(strPay)

ElseIf (intStateTax + intFedTax + intFICA) > intGrossPay Then
    MessageBox.Show("Error: Withholdings are too much.")

End If
Next
End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

After using a Do-Until Loop and getting the counter to increment, I realized that loop was not beneficial to this project at all. It only allowed user to enter the payroll information for one employee and then copied that information to the other three employees.

So I ended up counting the instances of employer data enter a different way altogether. I added an "Employer Number" textbox and incremented the value by for each button click as shown on this in this youtube tutorial: http://youtu.be/qK45UI3dlP0.

So now the code looks like this:

```
        Private Sub btnCalculate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCalculate.Click
    Dim intGrossPay As Double   ' To hold gross pay.
    Dim intStateTax As Double   ' To hold state tax withholding.
    Dim intFedTax As Double     ' To hold fed tax withholding.
    Dim intFICA As Double       ' To hold FICA withholding.
    Dim intNetPay As Double     ' To hold net pay.
    Dim strPay As String        ' To hold output.



    If Val(txtEmployeeNumber.Text) < 5 Then
        'Calculate gross pay.
        intGrossPay = txtHourlyPayRate.Text * txtHoursWorked.Text

        'Calculate state income tax withholding.
        intStateTax = intGrossPay * txtStateTaxRate.Text

        'Calculate fed tax withholding.
        intFedTax = intGrossPay * txtFedTaxRate.Text

        ' Calculate FICA witholding.
        intFICA = intGrossPay * txtFICA.Text

        'Calculate net pay.
        intNetPay = intGrossPay - (intStateTax + intFedTax + intFICA)
        If (intStateTax + intFedTax + intFICA) < intGrossPay Then
            ' Create a string to display.
            strPay = ("Employee number" & ": " & (Val(txtEmployeeNumber.Text)) & "Gross pay is " & (intGrossPay.ToString("C")) & ". " &
                "State tax withholding is " & (intStateTax.ToString("C")) & ". " & "Federal tax withholding is " & (intFedTax.ToString("C")) &
                ". " & "FICA withholdings is " & (intFICA.ToString("C")) & ". " & "Net pay is " & (intNetPay.ToString("C")) & ". ")

            ' Add string to listbox."
            lstEmployeePay.Items.Add(strPay)

        ElseIf (intStateTax + intFedTax + intFICA) > intGrossPay Then
            MessageBox.Show("Error: Withholdings are too much.")
        End If
        txtEmployeeNumber.Text = Val(txtEmployeeNumber.Text) + 1
    End If
End Sub
```